# Why does a JavaFx Application HAVE to be launched from within its own class?

Tags: java, javafx

I tried the following code and was forced to launch my JavaFx application called `Viewer` without directly calling the method `launch`.

Here is the JavaFx class:

```
package Freelance;

public class Viewer extends Application
{
    private WebEngine myWebEngine;

    public void start(Stage stage)
    {
        stage.setTitle("Browser");

        WebView myBrowser = new WebView();
        myWebEngine = myBrowser.getEngine();
        myWebEngine.getLoadWorker().exceptionProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Throwable>()
        {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Throwable> observableValue, Throwable oldException,
                    Throwable exception)
            {
                System.out.println("WebView encountered an exception loading a page: " + exception);
            }
        });
        myBrowser.setPrefSize(1600, 900);

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        root.setCenter(myBrowser);
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        stage.show();
        myWebEngine.load("http://www.google.com/");

    }

    public static void run()
    {
        launch("");
    }

}
```

Now when I try to launch this from a separate class like so:

```
package Freelance;

public class Test
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Viewer.launch();
    }

}
```

I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Error: class Freelance.Test is not a subclass of javafx.application.Application
    at javafx.application.Application.launch(Application.java:254)
    at Freelance.Test.main(Test.java:8)
```

However, if I change the `Test` class like so:

```
package Freelance;

public class Test
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Viewer.run(); // Changed from using "launch()" to "run()"
    }

}
```

Then it works and launches properly.

So I was just curious as to why this happens or if I am writing the code in an incorrect format.

Thank you.

Comment: the docu is quite helpful , it describes the proper way to use the `launch()` method. Check [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Application.html)

Comment: By the way, you should be passing `args` to the `launch` method, not an empty string or empty array.  JavaFX will make them available in the [application parameters](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Application.html#getParameters--).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you take a look at `javafx.application.Apllication`'s implementation of `launch(String... args)`, you will find this code:

```
public static void launch(String... args) {
    // Figure out the right class to call
    StackTraceElement[] cause = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();

    boolean foundThisMethod = false;
    String callingClassName = null;
    for (StackTraceElement se : cause) {
        // Skip entries until we get to the entry for this class
        String className = se.getClassName();
        String methodName = se.getMethodName();
        if (foundThisMethod) {
            callingClassName = className;
            break;
        } else if (Application.class.getName().equals(className)
                && "launch".equals(methodName)) {

            foundThisMethod = true;
        }
    }

    if (callingClassName == null) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Error: unable to determine Application class");
    }

    try {
        Class theClass = Class.forName(callingClassName, false,
                           Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());
        if (Application.class.isAssignableFrom(theClass)) {
            Class<? extends Application> appClass = theClass;
            LauncherImpl.launchApplication(appClass, args);
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error: " + theClass
                    + " is not a subclass of javafx.application.Application");
        }
    } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
        throw ex;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
}
```

As you see, the foreach-loop iterates over the stack-trace. This means: your need to call the `launch(String... args)` method from within the class providing the `start()` method.

The answers of [fabian](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39748944/4216641) and [James_D](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39748944/4216641) provide examples on how to launch JavaFX Applications form within another class.

Answer (score 7):

Since `launch` is a static method, the application class cannot be determined by means other than inspecting the stack, since after compilation

```
Application.launch("");
```

ends up the same in the bytecode as

```
Viewer.launch("");
```

Inspecting the stack only works, if you can find the `Application` class somewhere in the stack, which is why `launch` needs to be called from the `Application` class.

There is an alternative however:
You could pass the `Application` class to [the overloaded version of the `launch` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Application.html#launch-java.lang.Class-java.lang.String...-):

```
Application.launch(Viewer.class, "");
```

Comment: I see. With the detail from @Turing85 below understand now.

Answer (score 4):

[It doesn't](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Application.html#launch-java.lang.Class-java.lang.String...-) have to be launched from within the `Application` subclass.

You can do

```
package Freelance;

import javafx.application.Application ;

public class Test
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Application.launch(Viewer.class, args);
    }

}
```